# Parameters of runnable not updating in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, runnable

I have an activity that has a runnable implemented in it. The parameters being passed into the runnable are extracted from the bundle when the activity starts. Once the runnable starts executing, it gets the same parameter, regardless of the value of the variable.
This is my runnable's code:

```
public String runnable_role_id=role_id;
public String runnable_id;

private Handler notify = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable_notify = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      check_notification(runnable_id,runnable_role_id);
        notify.postDelayed(this, 15000);
    }
};
```

role_id is defined globally, and its value is taken from:

```
role_id=bundle.getString("passing_role_id");
```